# Android Studio - Blurred background image

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make a splash page for my app. But for some reason the image I use as `android:background` becomes blurred and in grey. Is there a way to prevent this?

The image I use is a `.png` image and is located in the folder `drawable`

[image]

This is the result I get

[image]

And this is what is found in my `layout` folder inside the file `activity_splash.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/logo_addata"
         android:orientation="vertical">
     </LinearLayout>
```

And this is what's inside the `splash.java` file connected to `activity_splash.xml`

```
package com.example.eglu.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.eglu.test.Websocket.init;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    init.connect();

    Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    timerThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: try it by puting  image in drawable-nodpi folder only

Comment: That fixed it thanks ^^, didn't think about checking the `dpi` folders, for some reason the image was shrunked and recolored within those folder.

Comment: U r welcome bro .this happens a lot this drawable thing is a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it by puting your  image in drawable-nodpi folder only